# How to hide all class divs and toggle one id div?

Tags: jquery, html, hide, toggle

```
$("#btnSad").click(function() {
    $(".tgg").each(function () {
    if (.tgg.id != "sad") {$(.tgg).hide();
    $("#sad").slideToggle("slow");
};  
});
```

What I want:
For each div with class `.tgg`
If div's `id` is not `#sad` - then hide them,
div `#sad` - slideToggle (`#sad` also has class `.tgg`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('.tgg:not(#sad)').hide();
$('#sad').slideToggle('slow');
```